# How to resolve the VS2010's MSB6001 error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Our project has been recently migrated from VS2005 to VS2010. Compiling it on my desktop lead to random errors, mainly that one:

```
12>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(268,5): error MSB6001: Invalid command line switch for "link.exe". Not a valid Win32 FileTime.
12>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(268,5): error MSB6001: Parameter name: fileTime
```

I looked in the project property, in "linker" section then "command line". Nothing about filetime..

A complete VS2010 re-install did not fix the issue. Did you already seen that issue and did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: Did you try "greping" for FileTime or fileTime in all of your .vcxproj files?  When a group I worked with migrated a large project from VS2k5 to VS2010, we found a good amount of accumulated cruft in some of the .vcxproj files that didn't cause problems on VS2k5 but 2010 didn't like.  If I remember correctly, the problems were only seen on newer machines that never had vs2k5 installed previously.  Once the cruft was removed, the builds worked on all the machines, whether or not the machines ever had 2k5 installed.  But your particular error was not one we saw.

Comment: I guess I should mention that when we found the 2k5 cruft, I hand-edited it out of the .vcxproj files.  Not too hard since it's XML or something similar.  Be sure to edit it with vs2010 closed, or you may lose your edits or worse, really confuse vs2010.

Comment: @phonetagger That's a sounds right. I was wondering the same: if the migration helper in VS2010 did performed his job correctly. I will try to look that way. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Citrix from my desktop did solve the issue. (Unbelievable but true..)

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest update of the following file:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets

Here is the link of the latest version:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5D-rSG1AVXNVXBCUzNtU0RaRzg/edit

Answer (score 0):

Check include/exclude paths in your %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props file

In my case, I Removed $(path) from ExcludePath tag, and this fixed my MSB6001 error.